# XAMPP Control Panel v3.3.0 MySQL stopped starting the need for a new solution

Tags: mysql

How to deal with this problem : when I want to run XAMPP MySQL On Windows 11 I get this:

[image: Control Panel]

It was working till now...

I tried port changing from `3306` to `4000` or `8111`
Deleting folders from mysql folder
Adding to service
E.t.c..

Now in log file I see:

```
2023-09-29 19:18:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2023-09-29 19:18:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2023-09-29 19:18:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2023-09-29 19:18:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2023-09-29 19:18:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2023-09-29 19:18:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.27 started; log sequence number 47207; transaction id 8
2023-09-29 19:18:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2023-09-29 19:18:43 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2023-09-29 19:18:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 230929 19:18:43
2023-09-29 19:18:43 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2023-09-29 19:18:43 0 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: Table '.\mysql\db' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed
2023-09-29 19:18:43 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table '.\mysql\db' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed
2023-09-29 19:18:43 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Comment: try to repair the tables https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/repair-table.html

Comment: nbk thank you for your reply. I need to run mySQL server to repair the tables in the database, am I wrong?

Comment: besides of an backup, you must copy **all** Files from the data directory and then delete xampp and reinstal it  and copy the data you earlier saves